# python pandas merging two dataframe and dealing with duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

When I merge two data frame  based on 'Name' column in both daraframe, I get duplicated rows, and I want to keep the first one. How can I deal with it?

```
df1

     Name   Address
0    Amy    Nan
1    Breen  Nan
2    Carly  Nan

df2

     ID    Name   Address
0   1102   Amy    899 South
1   1105   Amy    700 Tower
2   1342   Breen  930 Tower
3   4674   Breen  555 Hall
4   5644   Breen  345 Young
5   2340   Carly  8988 House
```

after merging:

```
df1

    Name   Address
0   Amy    899 South
1   Amy    700 Tower
2   Breen  930 Tower
3   Breen  555 Hall
4   Breen  345 Young
5   Carly  8988 House
```

I want to make like this:

```
df1

    Name   Address
0   Amy    899 South
1   Breen  930 Tower
2   Carly  8988 House
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily once you already [merged](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) your dataframes.

I Personally merged your two dataframes like follows:

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1,df2,how='right')  # 'right' because we don't want Nan values do we ?
```

then all you want to do is to [drop duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) as follows:

```
df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'],keep='first',inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

output:

```
      Address   Name
0   899 South    Amy
2   930 Tower  Breen
5  8988 House  Carly
```

I hope this was helpful. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with map and without merge as you don't need the other columns from df2. Just need to handle the duplicates in df2 first.

```
df2_unique = df2.drop_duplicates('Name',keep='first')
df1['Address'] = df1['Name'].map(df2_unique.set_index('Name')['Address'])
```

You get

```
    Name    Address
0   Amy     899 South
1   Breen   930 Tower
2   Carly   8988 House
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you need to do merge here:

```
df2[['Name', 'Address']].drop_duplicates(subset=['Address'])
```

should take care of it.